# Why can a material mixture block all light?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, visible-light, chemical-compounds

Dyes and different colorings are often mixed into materials. These are usually a small fraction of the total material volume/mass and aren't painted on so don't have a uniform surface coat but some manage to block all light or all light from a certain wavelength.

How does this work? Why can widely/randomly spaces molecules block light?

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to "all light," it's important to clarify that you mean visible light, as other types of light, such as radio waves and x-rays, would most likely pass through your mixture. When dyes and colorings are added to a material, it becomes increasingly opaque, obstructing the passage of photons in the visible light frequency. Additionally, the transparency of a material can depend on polarization. Polarized glasses, for example, appear transparent until photons with a polarization perpendicular to the glasses are attempted to be transmitted. In such cases, those photons are absorbed, similar to how an opaque material would absorb them.